# Convert Text into a Formula in Calc

Tags: worksheet-function, find-and-replace, libreoffice-calc

I have a bunch of cells in a spreadsheet like the following:
1.48oz/12

I am trying to replace the oz/ with * and then calculate it.

So far I have:

```
=REPLACE(G4,FIND("oz/",G4),3,"*")
```

which yields:

```
=1.48*12
```

but I don't know how to make it calculate.
I tried:

```
="="&REPLACE(G4,FIND("oz/",G4),3,"*")
```

but it just yields a text string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, the answer is to use `VALUE()`.  It’s messy.  You can do it in one shot as:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(G4,FIND("oz/",G4)-1)) / VALUE(RIGHT(G4,LEN(G4)-FIND("oz/",G4)-2))
```

If you’re willing to tie up a column (which you can hide after you’ve finished debugging) with an intermediate value, you can define, say, `I4` as

```
=FIND("oz/",G4)
```

... and then define your ratio (computation result) as

```
=VALUE(LEFT(G4,I4-1)) / VALUE(RIGHT(G4,LEN(G4)-I4-2))
```

I’m not familiar with libreoffice-calc, so I don’t whether `VALUE()` is available there.

Comment: That works great, thanks. I tried a lot of different things, I didn't find that.